# Disable content bounce in WP8 Cordova app - disallowoverscroll does not work

Tags: html, css, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have the following code that I run in Visual Studio to deploy a Cordova app to a WP device. I added background colors to certain elements to see how the scrollable content is being rendered. When I scroll to bottom or top, the unordered list will bounce off its parent and the blue background will be visible. How do I render the list so that I only see a yellow background when the bottom or top of the list is reached?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>BlankCordovaApp7</title>

    <!-- BlankCordovaApp7 references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li>
        <li>18</li>
        <li>19</li>
        <li id="lastChild">20</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}

body {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

ul {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#lastChild {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I tried adding this to config.xml instead of setting `-ms-touch-action`, but it didn't work:

```
<preference name="disallowoverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Comment: As far as I know, the only way is body { -ms-touch-action:none; }

Comment: that disables scrolling on ul as well

Answer (score 0):

I just tried these two lines in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="disallowoverscroll" value="true"/>
```

and it seems to work :) ...

(Of course - my app becomes fullscreen ... but actually this is even better for me :) ... )